# Prevent user login before mount is complete

Tags: 18.04, mount, login, pam

All our workstations are Ubuntu 18. The `/home/`  is a network mount (nas). This is how it looks in `/etc/fstab`:

```
nas:/mnt/export/home    /home   nfs     nfsvers=3,_netdev       0       0
```

The problem is: when users boot their computer, they login before `fstab` is able to mount `/home/` which messes up their desktops and settings.

If it matters, the `/etc/fstab` file is being managed by puppet, along with everything else on workstations.

My question is, how can I prevent users from logging in before the `/home/` mount is complete? In other words, how can I make it so users would be able to login ONLY after the `/home/` mount is complete?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: There is no such Ubuntu version as 18. Do you mean 18.04?

Comment: Yes, David, I mean Ubuntu 18.04.